# jquery - change jquery object via parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

Sorry bad title. For the life of me I can't figure out a good way to do this. I've got a 
jquery object that is used to set a cookie. Throughout my code I use that cookie
to gather information from the user as well as perform various other functions. The problem is 
in certain instances I don't want the cookie name to be **'user-profile'** I want it to be **'admin-profile'.**
Is there a way to somehow pass in an option when I call **userProfile()** and change the cookie name? I want
the **'admin-profile'** cookie to basically do everything the **'user-profile'** cookie does. I'm a bit of a newb 
so code samples work best for me.

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.userProfile = function(opts) {

        var userProfileCookie = {
            name: 'user-profile',
            options: {
                path: '/',
                expires: 365
            }
        };

        function userHeightCookie() {
            var userData = $.parseJSON($.cookie(userProfileCookie.name));
            return(userData);
        };

        function readHeightCookie(userInfo) {
            $.cookie(userProfileCookie.name, JSON.stringify(userInfo), userProfileCookie.options);
        };

        function removeProfileCookie() { $.cookie(userProfileCookie.name, null, userProfileCookie.options); }

        if($(".slider").length > 0){
            $.cookie(userProfileCookie.name);
        }
    }})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () { $('#mastHead').userProfile(); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `opts` parameter for this:

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.userProfile = function(opts) {

        var name = (opts.name || 'user') + '-profile';
        var userProfileCookie = {
            name: name,
            options: {
                path: '/',
                expires: 365
            }
        };

        function userHeightCookie() {
            var userData = $.parseJSON($.cookie(userProfileCookie.name));
            return(userData);
        };

        function readHeightCookie(userInfo) {
            $.cookie(userProfileCookie.name, JSON.stringify(userInfo), userProfileCookie.options);
        };

        function removeProfileCookie() { $.cookie(userProfileCookie.name, null, userProfileCookie.options); }

        if($(".slider").length > 0){
            $.cookie(userProfileCookie.name);
        }
    }})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () { $('#mastHead').userProfile({ name: 'admin' }); });
```